# What's the fastest way to get data from an Excel file?

Tags: excel, vba, import

My task is to copy the range F1:F200 from several thousand Excel files, and paste them into adjacent columns in the destination folder. The macro works, but it takes  about 5 seconds for each file to open.

I thought about the "Get Data" query function, but I'm not familiar with it. I couldn't even determine if it's possible to import a single range and paste it where you need it.

Are there other methods of speeding up the process?

(I saw this post: [Read Excel file without opening it and copy contents on column first blank cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49242540/read-excel-file-without-opening-it-and-copy-contents-on-column-first-blank-cell), but I cannot attempt it for another 12 hours. I'm hoping that by then, someone will tell me that it's definitely faster, or definitely slower, or something.)

EDIT: I thought saying "open, copy, and paste" was sufficient description of the process, but it's probalby better to show you:

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
Dim StrFile As String
Dim aBook As Workbook, DestSheet As Worksheet
Dim dest As Range
Dim CurDir As String
Dim diaFolder As FileDialog

Set DestSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data modified")


' Chose directory 
MsgBox "Select Folder"
' Open the file dialog
Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
'FIX: how to make the current directory the default for diaFolder?
diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
diaFolder.Show

'This captures the Folder pathname
CurDir = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)

ChDir CurDir
'cleanup
Set diaFolder = Nothing

StrFile = Dir(CurDir & "\*.xls")    
Dim aCell As Range

Do While Len(StrFile) > 0

    ' First cell of destination range
    DestSheet.Range("T4").End(xlToRight).Offset(-3, 1).Select
    'Open a workbook
    Set aBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=StrFile, ReadOnly:=True)

    ' Copy from Column F and the Paste
    aBook.Sheets(1).Range("F1", Range("F65536").End(xlUp)).Copy 
    DestSheet.Paste

    ' Close the book
    aBook.Application.CutCopyMode = False
    aBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

    StrFile = Dir
Loop


MsgBox "Done"
```

Comment: Why copy to 65536 when you say you only need 200? How big are the source files? How fast is the disk they are on? Are they over a network? Can you put them on a local fast disk?

Comment: `What's the fastest way to get data from an Excel file?` Use OLEDB

Comment: Where are the files? If they're on a Sharepoint site, network drive or even USB(2.0) drive then there's probably a good argument for copying them to a local machine drive (maybe in batches) before attempting to read them.

Comment: If you do not have a problem with the code, but it takes a while to open the file, you can use adodb, but you need to know the name of the sheet. If thousands of sheet names are the same, you can import the data into adodb.

Comment: @Dy.Lee: Getting the name of the 1st sheet using OLEDB is pretty easy. But yes if one knows the name of the sheet and the column headers then we will not have to write code for getting those...

Comment: @SiddharthRout, If you do not know the sheet name, I do not know. An example would be a good experience.

Comment: @Dy.Lee: Ok. Let's wait for OP to respond and if required, I will post the code :) BTW you can use `Set rsTbl = conn.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables)` and then loop through it to get the sheetnames using `If Right(rsTbl.Fields!Table_Name.Value, 1) = "$" Then` to get the sheet name

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I expect a lot.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I have not tried it yet, but thanks for the good info.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I've tested your code and it's a great way to do it.

Comment: @SolarMike I don't copy to 65536. Range("F65536").End(xlUp) means "Starting at the bottom, go up until you get to a non-empty cell".  The whole command selects the range from F1 to that last cell (which is usually around 200, but I don't know for sure)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, to use your code, what do I have to know about OLEDB? I've never used it.

Comment: Is the first sheet name of the file to be collected the same?

Comment: @SiddharthRout, This gets the sheet names in alphabetical order, not in sheet order. How can I tell which sheet is the first sheet?

Comment: @Dy.Lee: For that you have to use DAO. DAO is the only library that retrieves the Sheet names by their ordinal position in the Workbook `Set wb = daoEngn.OpenDatabase("C:\Users\routs\Desktop\AB-Retainership\test.xls", False, True, "Excel 8.0;")` and then `For Each tbl In wb.TableDefs` to get `tbl.Name`

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson: I have couple of questions for you... `1` Do all workbooks have the same sheetname? `2` Does the column "F" have header? If yes, then is it the same in all files?

Comment: Also I noticed you are using `aBook.Sheets(1)` Do all the workbooks have 1 sheet? If not then `aBook.Sheets(1)` may not be the sheet that you may think it is :)

Comment: @Siddharth Rout,  I see.  I tested using  ado.

Comment: @SiddharthRout The workbooks all have one sheet, named "Report". (I think they were all automatically generated.) Column F has no header, but it does always say "Date" in Row 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a little faster

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Dim target As Range
Set target = DestSheet.Range("T4").End(xlToRight).Offset(-3, 1)

Do While Len(StrFile) > 0


    'Open a workbook
    Set aBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=StrFile, ReadOnly:=True)

    ' Copy from Column F and then Paste
    aBook.Sheets(1).Range("F1:F200").Copy
    target.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

    ' Close the book
   ' aBook.Application.CutCopyMode = False 'not needed
    aBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
 Set target = target.Offset(0, 1) 'move pointer 1 column right
    StrFile = Dir
Loop
```

Comment: I can see the advantage of the first two lines. And using Target.Offset. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a method to use oledb.

```
Dim Rs As Object

Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim StrFile As String
    Dim aBook As Workbook, DestSheet As Worksheet
    Dim dest As Range
    Dim CurDir As String
    Dim diaFolder As FileDialog
    Dim Fn As String
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim strSQL As String

    Set DestSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data modified")


    ' Chose directory
    MsgBox "Select Folder"
    ' Open the file dialog
    Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    'FIX: how to make the current directory the default for diaFolder?
    diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
    diaFolder.Show

    'This captures the Folder pathname
    CurDir = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)

    ChDir CurDir
    'cleanup
    Set diaFolder = Nothing

    StrFile = Dir(CurDir & "\*.xls")
    Dim aCell As Range

    strSQL = "Select * from [Report$F1:F65536] "

    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        Fn = CurDir & "\" & StrFile
        ' First cell of destination range
        Set Target = DestSheet.Range("T4").End(xlToRight).Offset(-3, 1)
        getRs Fn, strSQL
        Target.CopyFromRecordset Rs
        Rs.Close
        Set Rs = Nothing

        StrFile = Dir
    Loop


    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub

Sub getRs(Fn As String, strQuery As String)
    Dim strConn As String

    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & Fn & _
             ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"";"

    Set Rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Rs.Open strQuery, strConn

End Sub
```